# Unity IronPython ImportException: No module named __future__

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, ironpython

I've been using IronPython as part of my Unity project. This is the IronPython part of my code:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Tamir\final_project\Final_Project\Assets\Plugins\sunfish-master");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Tamir\final_project\Final_Project\Assets\Plugins\Lib");
dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Tamir\final_project\Final_Project\Assets\Plugins\sunfish-master\sunfish.py");
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
ImportException: No module named __future__
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.ThrowException (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions+LightException lightEx) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow (System.Object value) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2[T0,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet] (T0 arg0, T1 arg1) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext ctx) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope, Microsoft.Scripting.ErrorSink errorSink) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path, Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(string)
GameManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:83)
```

The error points at the line: engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Tamir\final_project\Final_Project\Assets\Plugins\sunfish-master\sunfish.py");

I've checked and there is a __ future __.py file in C:\Tamir\final_project\Final_Project\Assets\Plugins\Lib

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

go to cmd, run the command `pip install future` or `python -m pip install future` and it supposed to work